# Prevent scrolling with keypad

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used CSS to hide the scrollbar at the side of the browser. However, I am still able to scroll on the page using my keypad. Is there a way to make it impossible to scroll with the keypad on the page?

Comment: I need to ask: why on earth would you want to?

Comment: I just don't want the user to be able to scroll down on that webpage. I want that webpage to be static. For example, like this webpage: http://math.berkeley.edu/~hutching/personal/namesakes/index.html . But it's static only because there isn't enough text on it.

Comment: The problem with this is that you have no idea how big the user's browser window is. If they have a small smartphone screen, they might never be able to see everything you want them to see.

Comment: you have a valid point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 body, html { 
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Perhaps this is because I am using a navigation bar? It "works" when I set position to fixed, but of course that only creates the illusion that the page isn't moving.

Comment: updated the code. You might have to set your html element with a fixed height as well, that way the body inherits it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jquery solution, FWIW...blocks all up or down key presses

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 38 || event.which == 40){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
```